# Call function implementing type on instance by a pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers, typedef, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to implement subscriber-publisher pattern. My base class `Subscriber` doesn't have a listener method, it declares type `Handler` instead. The idea behind this is that a derived class will be able to have multiple handlers which will implement this type and can be passed to a `Publisher`. I'm trying to invoke a handler in `Notify` method, but I'm getting an error which states `expression must have pointer-to-member type`. How can I cast my function pointer to a member type and is it even possible with my approach?

```
class Subscriber {
public:
    typedef void (*Handler)();
};

struct Subscription {
    Subscriber *instance;
    Subscriber::Handler handler;
};

class Publisher {
protected:
    std::vector<Subscription> subscriptions;

public:
    virtual void AddSubscriber(Subscription subscription) {
        this->subscriptions.push_back(subscription);
    };

    virtual void Notify() {
        for (auto subscription : this->subscriptions) {
            auto i = subscription.instance;
            auto h = subscription.handler;

            (i->*h)();
        }
    };
};
```

My goal is to make an expandable system to be able to do something like this

```
struct KeyboardSubscription : Subscription {
    Event event_type;
    Key listened_key;
}

class GUI : Subscriber {
    void OpenMenu() { ... }; // implementing Subscriber::Handler
    void CloseMenu() { ... }; // implementing Subscriber::Handler too
}

class Keyboard : Publisher {
    void Notify() {
        for (KeyboardSubscription subscription : this->subscriptions) {
            auto i = subscription.instance;
            auto h = subscription.handler;
            
            if (subscription.event_type == this->event_type &&
                subscription.listened_key == this->pressed_key)
                (i->*h)();
        }
    }
}

int main() {
   // init GUI and Keyboard...

   KeyboardSubscription sub1;
   sub1.instance = gui_instance;
   sub1.handler = &GUI::OpenMenu;
   sub1.event_type = Key_Down;
   sub1.listened_key = Enter;

   KeyboardSubscription sub2;
   sub2.instance = gui_instance;
   sub2.handler = &GUI::CloseMenu;
   sub2.event_type = Key_Down;
   sub2.listened_key = Esc;

   keyboard_instance.AddSubscription((Subscription)sub1);
   keyboard_instance.AddSubscription((Subscription)sub2);
}
```

Comment: `(i->*h)();` -> `h()` ... no need for `i`. Or just `subscription->handler();` In your `auto h = subscription->handler;`, the deduced type for `h` is `Subscriber::Handler`, so no need for a cast. Or have I totally missed the point, here?

Comment: Or, if you *need* the instance in the handler function, you can add that as an argument: `typedef void (*Handler)(Subscriber*);` and then call in your `Notify` like `h(i);`. Maybe we need more details here, like a sample of usage code?

Comment: As it stands, your code doesn't declare `handler` as a member function; it is a data member whose type is a function pointer (to a *free* function).

Comment: why do you have a vector of pointers?

Comment: @AdrianMole I added an example to the question, take a look, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've achieved what I wanted. I just needed to declare a function type like this:

```
class Subscriber {
public:
    typedef void (Subscriber::*Handler)();
};
```

Here's a full example which compiles without any warnings and works as expected

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Subscriber {
public:
    typedef void (Subscriber::*Handler)();
};

struct Subscription {
    Subscriber *instance;
    Subscriber::Handler handler;
};

class Publisher {
protected:
    std::vector<Subscription*> subscriptions;

public:
    void AddSubscription(Subscription *subscription) {
        this->subscriptions.push_back(subscription);
    }

    virtual void Notify() {
        for (auto subscription : this->subscriptions) {
            auto i = subscription->instance;
            auto h = subscription->handler;

            (i->*h)();
        }
    }
};

struct KeyboardSubscription : Subscription {
    int event_type;
    int listened_key;
};

class GUI : Subscriber {
public:
    void OpenMenu() { // implementing Subscriber::Handler
        std::cout << "Open menu" << std::endl;
    }
    void CloseMenu() { // implementing Subscriber::Handler too
        std::cout << "Close menu" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Keyboard : Publisher {
private:
    int event_type;
    int pressed_key;

public:
    void AddSubscription(Subscription *subscription) {
        Publisher::AddSubscription(subscription);
    }

    void Notify() {
        for (auto sub : this->subscriptions) {
            KeyboardSubscription* subscription = static_cast<KeyboardSubscription*>(sub);
            
            auto i = subscription->instance;
            auto h = subscription->handler;
            
            if (subscription->event_type == this->event_type &&
                subscription->listened_key == this->pressed_key)
                (i->*h)();
        }
    }

    void Event1() {
        this->event_type = 10;
        this->pressed_key = 1;

        this->Notify();
    }

    void Event2() {
        this->event_type = 20;
        this->pressed_key = 2;

        this->Notify();
    }
};

int main() {
    GUI *gui_instance = new GUI;
    Keyboard *keyboard_instance = new Keyboard;

    KeyboardSubscription *sub1 = new KeyboardSubscription;
    sub1->instance = (Subscriber*)gui_instance;
    sub1->handler = (Subscriber::Handler)(&GUI::OpenMenu);
    sub1->event_type = 10;
    sub1->listened_key = 1;

    KeyboardSubscription *sub2 = new KeyboardSubscription;
    sub2->instance = (Subscriber*)gui_instance;
    sub2->handler = (Subscriber::Handler)(&GUI::CloseMenu);
    sub2->event_type = 20;
    sub2->listened_key = 2;

    keyboard_instance->AddSubscription((Subscription*)sub1);
    keyboard_instance->AddSubscription((Subscription*)sub2);

    keyboard_instance->Event1();
    keyboard_instance->Event2();
}
```

And the output is as follows:

```
Open menu
Close menu
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Maybe you don't need Subscription.like this

```
class Subscriber {
public:
  typedef void (*Handler)();
  Handler handler;
};
```

2.you just need to call handle() in Notify().like this

```
virtual void Notify() {
  for (auto &subscriber : this->subscribers) {
    subscriber->handler();
  }
};
```

Comment: Your example doesn't fit my needs, you call the `handler` by its name. But my goal is to make a generic function type, so I could pass any function implementing this type to a Publisher. I updated the question and added a example of behaviour I want to achieve. Take a look, please